# Loading firestore data in TabBarView

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I am trying to create a UI where in the home page, the user has 3 tabs: groups, events, friends.
I have built a `StreamBuilder` for each of the tabs, but when I switch between tabs, it throws an error, saying that the stream has already been listened to.

I need a way to "reset" the stream, so it could load again when im switching back to the tab, even though I've already listened to that stream.

Here is the code for the streamer - I currently only try to access the events data, later on there will be different streams for each tab.

```
Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> _streamer() async* { //this is currently the only streamer - it only loads events.   
  var userEventsDocument = await Firestore.instance
      .collection('userEvents')
      .document(widget.uid)
      .get();

  var userEvents = List.from(userEventsDocument["eventlist"]);
  List<DocumentSnapshot> eventsSnapshot = List();

  for (var i = 0; i < userEvents.length; i++) {
    eventsSnapshot.add(await userEvents[i].get());
  }

  yield eventsSnapshot;
}
```

This is how im using the streamer in the TabBarView:

```
TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children: [
  StreamBuilder(
    stream: _streamer(),
    //Firestore.instance.collection("Events").snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
      return SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
          42 -
          MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom -
          AppBar().preferredSize.height -
          kToolbarHeight,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data[index]),
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider();
                  },
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      );
    },
  ),
  StreamBuilder(
    stream: _streamer(),
    //Firestore.instance.collection("Events").snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
      return SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
            42 -
            MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom -
            AppBar().preferredSize.height -
            kToolbarHeight,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data[index]),
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider();
                  },
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      );
    },
  ),
  StreamBuilder(
    stream: _streamer(),
    //Firestore.instance.collection("Events").snapshots(),
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<List<dynamic>> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text("Loading...");
      return SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height -
            42 -
            MediaQuery.of(context).padding.bottom -
            AppBar().preferredSize.height -
            kToolbarHeight,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                child: ListView.separated(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                      _buildListItem(context, snapshot.data[index]),
                  separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return Divider();
                  },
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      );
    },
  ),
]),
```

Comment: Have you tried listening to the streams in a central place, with a state management solution, and then just drink the output of those streams?

Comment: could you explain a little bit more? im not really familiar with what you've mentioned

Comment: Are you using any sort of state management solution on your app, like Redux, BLoC, ScopedModel, Provider or something else?

Comment: I am not, iv'e read about BLoC but didnt really figure out how to implement it in my design

Comment: To get around the issue of trying to re-listen to an already listened to Stream, you would have to have those Streams somewhere central in your application, that is then passed to your Tabs. Instead of listening to the streams every time the Tab is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Ive managed to do this by passing widgets to the TabBarview:

```
body: TabBarView(controller: _tabController, children:
              [TestScreen1(), TestScreen2(), TestScreen3()],
),
```

Each of the TestScreens have a builder that return a listview, by using its own streambuilder.